# GetMyPriceForASIN on Amazon MWS API not working

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I am testing an sample API on Amazon MWS API for PHP. As I run the codes in the GetMyPriceForASIN sample, it does not return any response even an error response.

```
$ret = 'ASINList.ASIN.0.=000001ASS&ASINList.ASIN.1.=B00002YHY&ASINList.ASIN.2.=B01112Z4VW';
$request = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMyPriceForASINRequest();
$request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);
$request->setASINList($ret);
invokeGetMyPriceForASIN($service, $request);


function invokeGetMyPriceForASIN(MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Interface $service, $request){
try {
$response = $service->GetMyPriceForASIN($request);
$dom1 = new DOMDocument();
$dom1->loadXML($response->toXML());
$dom1->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom1->formatOutput = true;
echo $dom1->saveXML(); 
} catch (MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Exception $ex1) {
    echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex1->getMessage() . "\n");
    echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
    echo("Error Code: " . $ex1->getErrorCode() . "\n");
    echo("Error Type: " . $ex1->getErrorType() . "\n");
    echo("Request ID: " . $ex1->getRequestId() . "\n");
    echo("XML: " . $ex1->getXML() . "\n");
    echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $ex1->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
}
}
```

as I try to debug it myself I have been stuck until this set of codes

```
public function getMyPriceForASIN($request){    
if (!($request instanceof MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMyPriceForASINRequest)) {
require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/Model/GetMyPriceForASINRequest.php');
$request = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMyPriceForASINRequest($request);
}

    $parameters = $request->toQueryParameterArray();
    $parameters['Action'] = 'GetMyPriceForASIN';
    $httpResponse = $this->_invoke($parameters);

    require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/Model/GetMyPriceForASINResponse.php');
    $response = MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMyPriceForASINResponse::fromXML($httpResponse['ResponseBody']);
    $response->setResponseHeaderMetadata($httpResponse['ResponseHeaderMetadata']);
    return $response;
}
```

on this code I encountered an error

```
$parameters = $request->toQueryParameterArray();
```

it does not return any array and i dont know where to find the function.
I also wonder that it might be that my ASIN list format was wrong, this is the format.

```
ASINList.ASIN.0.=000001ASS&ASINList.ASIN.1.=B00002YHY&ASINList.ASIN.2.=B01112Z4VW
```

Comment: What is that function `test1`? Can you please fix it, because now it uses undefined variables `$response`, `$x`, doesn't return anything unless exception is caught... It does something weird. Or exclude it if it's irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer its in my ASIN List format that is wrong. I used this codes to format my ASIN List correctly

```
$asin_list = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_ASINListType();
$ret = $asin_list->setASIN($xml_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this before `$request->setASINList($ret);`

```
require_once "MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMyPriceForASINRequest";
$asin_list = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_ASINListType();
$asin_list->setASIN($asins_array);
```